Prevent italics in code or verbatim strings in org mode
In an Org mode file, I have:
="a man".gsub(/a/, 'z')=

~"a man".gsub(/a/, 'z')~

the /a/ in code and verbatim string is italicized when it shouldn't be. How can I prevent this ?
Here's a screenshot:


AFAIK, it's not possible to avoid the italics in this situation (unless you forego fontification of emphasis components altogether). In some situation, you can use zero-length spaces to avoid misinterpretations but I don't see how they could help avoid it in this case - see Emphasis and Monospace in the manual.
